# Is it possible to use Devel to create a "mad libs" style profile2 registration page?

Tags: theming, users, debugging

I've got the template file working, however `<?php dpm($page); ?>` and `<?php dpm($content); ?>` aren't getting me what I need to isolate the forms. I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812949/how-would-you-approach-creating-a-mad-libs-style-form-in-drupal but it's a little over my head.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Drupal Answers! Which template file are you using, and which code are you using to tell Drupal to use it?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thank you, I'm using "page--profile2test.tpl", profile2test being the URL path I set under unique registration path. I'm using a theme_hook_suggestions preprocess page function I found somewhere. Here it is http://pastebin.com/1TX1hgLy